# Stop screensaver and lock session on Debian by command line

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, screensaver, gnome3

I tried several ways to stop the screensaver and the lock session but I can't fix it.

I went to the settings but there isn't any "never" for the screensaver timer. The minimum is 1 minute, the maximum 1 hour.
`System Settings > Power Management ..`
I didn't find the solution of this issue.

I tried `xset -dpms` `xset s off` and `setterm -powersave off` (but I have a argument error).

Nothing works.

Does anyone have an idea?

I'm with Debian 7 after a PXE installation on a `Gigabytes Brix 2955`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Some background

First, let's pick apart what you've tried.

The commands

```
xset -dpms
```

and

```
xset s off
```

control the [X Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (the piece of software actually responsible for presenting you with a graphical display and managing input devices on it, such as mouse) directly, while

```
setterm -powersave off
```

is meant only for what are called ["virtual consoles"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) in Linux ("term" there comes from the word "terminal", and Linux virtual consoles emulate [terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal); let's not dig deeper for now).  These are those "scary" text-only interfaces which you see when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> (where `n` is 1 to 6, typically); use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> there to switch back to X.

But you are not using the X server directly.  Instead, what you interact with is the so-called ["desktop environment" (DE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)—a set of programs responsible for actually presenting you with windows, ways to manage them and other stuff you expect to be available (like system menu for logging off / rebooting / the clock etc).  The DE itself controls the X server and that's why your attempts at using `xset` were in vain.

Debian ships many DEs (GNOME, KDE, XFCE, LXDE to name a few) and they have different appearances, settings etc.  By default, Debian 7 installs [GNOME](http://gnome.org), specifically, GNOME 3 (GNOME 3 received a major redesign since the 2.x series provoking both many praises and curses).

Consequently, when you use a dialog called "System settings", that's not really *system* settings (in a literal sense) but rather *GNOME's system* settings. So really when you're googling for screensaver problems "in Debian" you should better search for GNOME 3 screensaver problems.

### What to do

#### Switching off automatic screen blanking (built-in screensaver)

GNOME project adopted a policy of constantly dumbing down the setting dialogs so I reckon they've just thought you wouldn't ever need to turn off screen blanking.

The solution is to install the so-called "GNOME Tweak Tool"—an external program wich allows tweaking settings not made available by GNOME's native dialogs.

Use

```
# apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

(or whatever method you're using to install packages) to install it and then run it and tweak the screensaver settings however you wish.

#### Manually locking the screen

Contrary to, say, Windows, where the screensaver is a part of "the shell" (called Explorer), under GNOME (and most other desktop environments or window managers in the GNU/Linux land) screen locking is done by a separate program, and Debian ships many of them.

So you have to:

1. Find out what screensaver program you have at hand;

   You most probably have the [`gnome-screensaver`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnome-screensaver) package installed which provides the `/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command` program.
2. Bind some key combination in GNOME to ru it.

   This one is trickier. You have to use the keyboard preferences configuration dialog and pick a key combo to run that program.

   Google tells me in GNOME this dialog is located in "System Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Shortcuts".

   First, check to see if that dialog *already* contains an entry for "screen saver" or "screen locking" of something like that.  If so, just learn the shortcut or pick your own and set it. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> might be a good pick—just like in Windows (and I personally prefer <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>).

   If there's no pre-cooked entry for locking the screen, add a custom one—running the program we've already discussed.

More info [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) and elsewhere on the internets—just google for GNOME+screensaver.

Comment: You were right. I searched with `Gnome 3` and I found these command lines. `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0`. Everything is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on Debian 9:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the screen lock yet but, this command worked for a gaming keyboard with an l.e.d. back light on Debian for me. The keyboards  instructions applied to Windows and not Linux. Now i can see my keyboard in the dark, Thanks.  I had been trying to figure this one out for a year or two.

```
# sudo  xset led on
```